# Sony Vaio Wireless connections stopped working

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, sony-vaio

After waking up my VAIO VPCEC laptop from standby, the wireless adapter seems to have stopped working on Windows 7. I cannot connect to the internet without an ethernet cable; the wireless networks icon in the taskbar shows no connections, and the light next to the wireless switch doesn't turn on. Clicking on the "troubleshoot network problems" just prompts me to connect an ethernet cable to the computer.

Currently, I am on my Ubuntu side (via dual-boot) and it's working fine, so it must be something in Windows. When I restart Windows, the wireless light turns on at the login screen, but as soon as I log in, it turns off. I did not install any drivers or change any settings; it just seems to have stopped working after waking up from standby.
I would greatly appreciate any recommended steps that I should take in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was an issue with the SmartWi application, where it would just shut off the wireless on its own. He opened up the SmartWi interface and changed the Wifi toggle to "on", and that's all that it took to fix that issue.

So, **toggle Wifi to "on" inside SmartWi** to solve this issue.

<sub>Moved answer out of question, the first paragraph was mainly [written by TNC](https://superuser.com/q/342137/9666).</sub>